# Memory Issue: Creating Bigrams and Trigrams with CountVectorizer

Tags: python, memory, tf-idf, countvectorizer

I am trying to create a document term matrix using CountVectorizer to extract bigrams and trigrams from a corpus.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

lemmatized = dat_clean['lemmatized']


c_vec = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(2,3), lowercase = False)
ngrams = c_vec.fit_transform(lemmatized)
count_values = ngrams.toarray().sum(axis=0)
vocab = c_vec.vocabulary_
df_ngram = pd.DataFrame(sorted([(count_values[i],k) for k,i in vocab.items()], reverse=True)
        ).rename(columns={0: 'frequency', 1:'bigram/trigram'})
```

I keep getting the following error:

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 7.89 TiB for an array with shape (84891, 12780210) and data type int64

While I have some experience with Python, I am pretty new to dealing with text data. I was wondering if there was a more memory efficient way to address this issue.

I'm not sure if it is helpful to know, but the `ngrams` object is a scipy.sparse._csr.csr_matrix.

Comment: I'm guessing you have 84,891 documents with a total of 12,780,210 unique terms, correct?

Comment: Is it fair to say that your error occurred on the line:  count_values = ngrams.toarray().sum(axis=0)

Comment: Yes, I believe that's where the error is occurring as it is unable to allocate sufficient memory to create the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**:

Here is one way to get the final table your looking for with frequency and bigram/trigram without generating the entire document term matrix. We can take the sum of a sparse matrix and use that to create a dataframe. This removes the need to create space in RAM for all of those missing values.

```
# Here we create columns as vocabulary terms and a single row value as count of all terms.
# We tranpose that to make it an index and a single column
data = ngrams.sum(axis=0)
keys = c_vec.vocabulary_.keys()
df_ngram = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=keys).T

# Get the count to its own column and rename all columns
df_ngram.index.name = 'bigram/trigram'
df_ngram.rename({0: 'count'}, inplace=True, axis=1)
df_ngram.reset_index(inplace=True)

# Calculate frequency of each term
df_ngram['frequency'] = (df_ngram['count'] / df_ngram['count'].sum())
df_ngram.sort_values(by=['count'], ascending=False, inplace=True)

df_ngram.head()

#   bigram/trigram  count   frequency
# 1 (ngram here)    (data) (data)
```

This could likely be simplified but it certainly does the job.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is brilliant and, I think, more computationally efficient.